# Windows 98 networking doesn't work in QEMU

Tags: networking, qemu

I installed Windows 98 in QEMU. I want to run networking in user mode. I start it with `qemu-system-i386 win98.img -m 256 -soundhw sb16` so it should be using default network hardware and probably working. In Network adapters section of Device manager I see only "Telephone adapter" (not sure about translation), no other NIC. I think that's the problem, anyway here are other details: I tried setting the IP address manually to 10.0.2.16, nothing changed in output of `ipconfig /all`. `ping 10.0.2.2` reports destination host unreachable. `ipconfig /all` reports only one interface, Ethernet adapter, its description is "PPP Adapter".

Comment: Which hardware did you select in Qemu? Did that include a NIC? If it did, which model is it emulating? Are there drivers for that model in win98 (if not it will be an unknown device in 98's device manager).

Comment: I edited it to add the command I used to start it. I also tried `-net nic,model=e1000`, no change. There's no unknown device in device manager. That's all I did to select hardware.

Comment: necro bumping, but did you manage to solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Windows 98 likely can't detect the Plug&Play BIOS. To work around this, configure your windows for direct hardware access. To do so, go to Device Manager, locate the Plug&Play Bios with the yellow exclamation mark, Properties, Update Driver, Select Location, List all Devices, then select "PCI Bus".

This will find a bunch of devices, such as the graphics card, better IDE drivers and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case try installing the PCI bus device manually, even if the Plug and Play wizard doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that msw98 does not recognise Plug&Play BIOS, hence it cannot see the PCI NIC at all. My hack is to define ISA NIC:

```
-net nic,model=ne2k_isa,irq=3,iobase=768,macaddr=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:00 
-net user
```

and manualy install driver: Standard National Semiconductor NE2000Plus

The `IRQ-3` and `IO=768(=0x300-0x31F)` is the ms-windows default settings, if you need st. else, be carefull with configuration.

BTW: I can browse the Internet, but cannot connect to samba server. The reason may be the new version of server's samba which ignore the too old version msw98 samba.

I use something like this:

```
qemu-system-i386 -name msw98 -M pc -m 256 -cpu pentium3,kvm=off \
    -smp cpus=1 -rtc-base localtime -display sdl -vga cirrus \
    -hda diskC.qcow2 -cdrom CD98SE.iso \
    -net nic,model=ne2k_isa,irq=3,iobase=768,macaddr=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:00 \
    -net user \
    -serial none -parallel none -no-kvm -no-acpi \
;
```

Please, drop a note, about your luck.