# QEMU: Windows 10 Host to win98 guest, configuring network

Tags: windows-10, qemu, windows-98

I began to post my question on stackoverflow, and my post has been closed with a message to post it here. I hope it's the right place for that. I think il will program a frontend for it for windows but i need to understand before how it works, and be sure i will use it for a long time.

I try to configure QEMU, on a windows host machine, it's new for me. I used VMWare and VirtualBox and would to try with it.

My purpose is to have a guest machine on the same network (192.168.1.xxx) like the others.
I read a lot of pages i think one could help me to do it, but i can't find it again.

it was something about a tap device to install...

What i tried:

- since my first post i found that installing [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/) give a tap adaptater for windows  hosts.
- I shared my connexion with this adapter
- I ran with parameter "-nic tap,ifname=OpenVPN_TAP" but i don't see any cards on windows guest
- I tried  "-netdev tap,id=mynet0,ifname=OpenVPN_TAP -k fr -device ne2k_pci,netdev=mynet0" but no card after a win98 hardware detection. When i force an install and reboot os says my card has problem.

It's just luck because i used a frontend that doesn't work and seen a link in its parameters to openvpn.

Thanks for your help.

Edit:

- For the problem about recognizing cards problem came from a device called "plug n play bios", i updated driver by forcing manually to "PCI BUS" according to this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/909206/windows-98-networking-doesnt-work-in-qemu)
- Card is now installed, but network has a bad ip.

Edit 2:

- On my host TAP devices had an overlay, i stopped to share connection then shared again, and overlay disappeared.
- Now i understand TAP acts like a router, i have an ip, i can't ping my others pcs but i can connect to WAN... it's not what i would to :/, i need to be on the same lan than my others machines

Comment: Making QEMU emulate a virtual NIC and making QEMU connect that NIC to the host's TAP interface are two different problems. Focus on fixing the emulation first, using the simplest networking mode available (probably 'user'); once you have the card show up inside the guest _then_ try to make it talk to the host via TAP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i read another post about it, i will edit for others that helped me. In devices manager, there is a "bios plug n play" that was shown with a warning, after have updated the driver to recognize it as "PCI Bus", it seems devices are detected now. I need more information for the while, because i must reinstall a lot of devices.